# Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE does not get fired for DisplayObjects added to a ScrollContainer

Tags: actionscript-3, starling-framework

I'm using Starling + Feathers + StarlingMVC to build a small game.

Doing that, I'm having an issue with ScrollContainer : it seems like elements (Buttons in my case) added to a ScrollContainer do not fire the Event.ADDED event and as a result do not get themed.

Here is a pastebin containing [the adding code](http://pastebin.com/0mSh8NQG) : _shopButton as well as _shopRPButton are visible when I test my game because I specify their textures, but _startButton is not, because it should get themed.

Here is my [custom theme's code](http://pastebin.com/BhTqrVFM), which contains a trace() statement inside buttonInitializer

And here is the related tracelog (I would have put a pastebin link but my reputation isn't high enough to post more than two links

> feathers-header-item
>   feathers-header-item
>   feathers-simple-scroll-bar-thumb
>   feathers-simple-scroll-bar-thumb
>   feathers-simple-scroll-bar-thumb
>   feathers-simple-scroll-bar-thumb
>   feathers-simple-scroll-bar-thumb
>   feathers-simple-scroll-bar-thumb

As you can see, the trace() statement gets called for ScrollContainer related items, but not for my buttons.

What am I doing wrong?

Regards,
Brice

Comment: Rather than providing a link to a pastebin, could you produce the sections of the code you are having a problem with here?

Comment: Well, no line produces an error. It's just the outcome that is not what I would have expected.

I managed to work around this problem by only adding my Buttons to the ScrollContainer after it has been added to stage and this way it is working... but it's a workaround at best and I guess there is something I'm not doing correctly.